# For loop causing a black screen in JFrame(Eclipse)

Tags: java, swing, loops, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

Here's my code and I'm trying to do a project for school but it's not working for some odd reason whenever I add a loop it causes the second JFrame to be completely black..
It's supposed to switch between Buttons A B and C once it's clicked

Comment: You're essentially blocking the Event Dispatching Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Yes, but I don't have a runnable example of your code, so I don't know where you might start

Comment: I'd first reduce the number of frames you have, maybe using a `CardLayout` first.  I'd make use of `pack` to set the initial size of the window and I would call `setVisible` on the frame (`z`) only after you have prepared the UI, because you code works fine for me, but I might not be running it the same way you are.  Your `while (x > 0)` won't run, because `x` is initialised to `0`

Comment: I added the runner and fixed the (x>=0) but now it gives me a black screen in the JFrame

Comment: Also packed it instead of using the resolution

Comment: Call `setVisible` last, after you added all you components to the window.

Comment: Now it's just a blank JFrame rather than a black one

Comment: Yep, you `while-loop` is now blocking the Event Dispatching Thread.  You're thinking in to linear a fashion, like you would for a console based application, this is not how GUI's work, they event driven.  Some event occurs, you get notified about it and perform what ever actions you need to do based on the state and the event

Comment: So how would I have to fix it then ? Any hints ? :/

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the answer I provided below 20 minutes ago?

Answer (score 2):

Taking some wild guesses at you intentions, you are simply thinking to much in a linear fashion, a lot like you would for a console based application, but a GUI is a event driven environment.  Something happens, you get told about, you react to.

Basically, you should be calling `setVisible` last, after you've prepared the base IU.

You need to get rid of your `while-loop`, it's not going to do what you want it to do.  Instead, you need to use a single `ActionListener` which can, based on the value of `x`, determine what should happen when any of the buttons are clicked, for example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Game());
    }

    private int counter;
    private int x;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter = 0;
        JFrame y = new JFrame("Game");
        y.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton start = new JButton("Start game");
        y.add(start, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        y.pack();
        JLabel a = new JLabel();
        a.setText("<HTML><body><H1>Instructions</H1><p>Click the 'start' button to start the game" + "<br>Click as many of the red buttons as you can before time runs out!<p></body></HTML>");
        y.add(a);
        y.pack();
        y.setVisible(true);
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Timer time = new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You got " + counter + " points");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                time.start();
                JFrame z = new JFrame("Sequence game");
                FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(0, 50, 40);
                z.getContentPane().setLayout(fl);
                JButton a = new JButton("A");
                Font f = a.getFont();
                Font myFont = f.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, f.getSize() * 4);
                a.setSize(200, 100);
                a.setVisible(true);
                JButton b = new JButton("B");
                b.setVisible(true);
                b.setSize(200, 100);
                JButton c = new JButton("C");
                c.setVisible(true);
                c.setSize(200, 100);
                z.setSize(1280, 1024);
                z.getContentPane().add(a);
                z.getContentPane().add(b);
                z.getContentPane().add(c);
                Random r = new Random();

                x = r.nextInt(3);
                ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (x == 0 && e.getSource().equals(a)) {
                            counter++;
                            x = r.nextInt(3);
                            a.setFont(f);
                        } else if (x == 1 && e.getSource().equals(b)) {
                            counter++;
                            x = r.nextInt(3);
                            b.setFont(f);
                        } else if (x == 2 && e.getSource().equals(c)) {
                            counter++;
                            x = r.nextInt(3);
                            c.setFont(f);
                        }

                        switch (x) {
                            case 0:
                                a.setFont(myFont);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                b.setFont(myFont);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                b.setFont(myFont);
                                break;
                        }
                        z.revalidate();
                        z.repaint();
                    }
                };

                System.out.println(x);
                switch (x) {
                    case 0:
                        a.setFont(myFont);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        b.setFont(myFont);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        b.setFont(myFont);
                        break;
                }
                z.revalidate();
                z.repaint();

                a.addActionListener(listener);
                b.addActionListener(listener);
                c.addActionListener(listener);

                z.pack();
                z.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```